# Kali Linux upgrade fails on Metasploit with hash checksum error

Tags: apt, kali-linux, upgrade, hashsum, checksum

I have just created a fresh boot of Kali Linux in order to begin learning penetration testing and security vulnerabilities so hopefully I can find a few 0days, then sell information on them to businesses and governmental organizations, as I understand there are a few now who are interested in acquiring these in a legitimate commercial context.

For this I assume I will benefit from having the latest version of Metasploit for testing. However, when I run `apt-get upgrade` the update process fails with errors:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.hands.com/kali/pool/main/m/metasploit-framework/metasploit-framework_4.14.1-0kali1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:5a3f9ee9247a9f32f53873d623c6b275bb11eafa95381aa9d6ecc9724e17518c
    - SHA1:df8606fdc1edb4b4b7f36e068d0789bd0d7289e0 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:677eef194091cfb557219e446d87d753 [weak]
    - Checksum-FileSize:71593968 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:c1068062a2da53e1ff1444360720ab4b787d058197e0ca568b330d9fd12fae4e
    - SHA1:900394222f17ddcfd52284b3f0eeeb391ad1089a [weak]
    - MD5Sum:29f15c23a3932e868157a291e44a2720 [weak]
    - Checksum-FileSize:71593968 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Thu, 09 Mar 2017 09:03:20 +0000
```

Adding the `--fix-missing` flag seems to cause the upgrade process to proceed further, so I *think* the system has otherwise now been properly updated, but it still eventually quits out with the same error message. Of course I am wary (to say the least!) about attempting to download an updated version of Metasploit from unofficial sources... but it also seems odd that the default repo is giving a hash sum mismatch.

Does anyone have an idea of what's going wrong here and what the correct methodology is to go about fixing it?

(Current result of running `cat /etc/issue`

```
Kali GNU/Linux Rolling \n \l
```

)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by running `msfupdate` as a separate command. Once I had done so I ran `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get upgrade` again, and this time the upgrade proceeded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your terminal:

```
# apt-get clean
# rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# apt-get update
```

I hope this fixes your problem.